# Sklearn: 'RidgeCV' object has no attribute 'cv_values_' error

Tags: scikit-learn, regression

I want to do 5-fold ridge CV and look at the cv_values_, but after some searching can't find a way to do it.

It seems if I add store_cv_result=True, then another error message says I can't do 5 fold CV.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [Scikit documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.RidgeCV.html#sklearn.linear_model.RidgeCV).

**store_cv_values : boolean, default=False**

**"This flag is only compatible with cv=None (i.e. using Generalized Cross-Validation)."**

For some reason, saving cv_values_ has only been implemented for LOOCV so far.